# Parsing listdata in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, jsonparser

I have a list .I am trying to json dump and load it and get specific data out of it but its not working.

```
x=[
 AttributeDict({
'address': '0xf239F8424AffCbf9CC08Bd0110F0Df011Bcd2e68',
'logIndex': 0,
'args': AttributeDict({
  '_value': 63
}),
'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x96d06e0f112247fd584cfe9fbdf726d172ec0703bad3604c1182e0abcb67a45a'),
'event': 'Energy',
'blockHash': HexBytes('0x3ee6e9f4d682d9a99a94828e9ad7eb7e009e464aed980cd6c3055f62703599fa'),
'blockNumber': 1327084,
'transactionIndex': 0
})
]
```

This is the reposnse above.
I need to get the "_value" out of it so
i first did the dump..

```
y = json.dumps(x)
```

and then loads

```
z = json.loads(y)
```

but i am not getting any data by putting e.g.

```
z['AttributeDict']
```

how can i get that out of it?? thanks

Comment: by doing type(x) it shows it as a list.. how to get data out of that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is,there is a module in web3.py called 
web3.datastructures so just doing by that code below you can get the values out of it

```
import web3.datastructures as wd
res=wd.AttributeDict(x[0])
print(res['args']['_value'])
```